# Add new item to recyclerview at the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I add a new item to my recyclerview with:

```
dbHelper.insertAusgabe(tag,datum,ausgabe,menge,kategorie);
Model model = new Model(tag,datum,kategorie,ausgabe,menge);
rvList.add(model);
modelAdapter.notifyItemInserted(rvList.size()-1);
```

Recyclerview:

```
modelAdapter = new ModelAdapter(rvList,ScrollingActivity.this);

RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(ScrollingActivity.this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setFocusable(false);
recyclerView.requestFocus();
```

The item gets successfully added but at the bottom of the recyclerview and not at the top as it should. 
[image]

Comment: Add item at the top of the list that adapter is holding. Eg: list.add(0, model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you added it at the bottom of your list too..

`rvList.add(model);` should be `rvList.add(0, model);`

and notify your recyclerview not like this

`modelAdapter.notifyItemInserted(rvList.size()-1);` but like this `modelAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with your list.

```
            Collections.reverse(rvList);
```